# How I turn label in asp red

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I would like to turn label red in .aspx when user enters wrong answer into textbox.

but not know how, hw I can do this?

Comment: Are you using asp or asp.net? For asp.net you can use CustomValidator for server-side answer check and required field validator

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using javascript (call this code from `onchange` of the textbox):

```
<label for="myTextBox" id="myLabel">For my textbox</label>
<input id="myTextBox" onchange="ValidateAnswer();">

function ValidateAnswer() {
    var txtBox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
    if(txtBox.value != "answer") {
       document.getElementById('myLabel').style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

You can also use the Validator controls if you're using ASP.Net:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvAnswer"
    ControlToValidate="myTextBox"
    ErrorMessage="required"
    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateAnswer"
    ValidateEmptyText="true"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ValidationGroup="First"
    ForeColor="red" >
</asp:CustomValidator>

function ValidateAnswer(sender, args) {
  args.IsValid = args.Value != "" && args.Value == "answer here";
  if(!args.IsValid) {
     document.getElementById('myLabel').style.color = 'red';
  }
  return;   
}
```

Comment: You  are not changing the label you are changing the textbox - op is looking for label color change (referring to client code).

Answer (score 1):

From the server side code:

```
  if(this.txtBox.Text.Length == 0) 
      {
        //no value entered
        lblMyLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
        lblMyLabel.Text = "Invalid entry";
      }
```

Client side you can do this:

Markup:

```
 <asp:TextBox onchange="Validate();" runat="server" id="myTextBox"/>
```

JS:

```
function Validate()
 {
  var t = document.getElementByID("myTextBox");
  var l = document.getElementByID("myLabel");
  if (t.Length == 0) 
       {
         l.style.backgroundColor='red';
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, some server side, and some client side, but in both cases it involves validation.  Essentially you are looking to change a css class or other style property on the label.

Answer (score 0):

C# code behind:

```
if(yourConditionText != "YourExpectedValue")
{
    youTextBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Server side button click event (which will be automatically generated when you double click on the button in Design view of the aspx page):

```
 protected void Button_Click(...)
    {
        if(txtYourTextBox.Text != "YourDesiredValue")
        {
            lblYourLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Better still, you could use String.Compare (recommended) as below:

```
if(string.Compare(txtYourTextBox.Text, "YourDesiredValue") != 0) //0 = Match
{
    lblYourLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red; //For backColor set BackColor property
}
```

Hope it helps!